# How can I filter by fiscal year in cognos report?

Tags: filter, report, cognos-10

I have a report and I want it to be filtered by fiscal year 2015 Jul-now. How can it be done in the report filter? I cannot use if-else in the filter. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution would be to implement a calendar table at the database level, consisting of calendar dates linked in to their financial weeks, periods and years.

Comment: Yes I've done this but did not work. It only shows data from jul 2015-dec 2015. I've no idea why.

Then I did this in my report filter >>>> (year([Presentation View].[Time Dimension].[PO Date] ) = [Presentation View].[Time Dimensional Fiscal Year].[FYear]
and month([Presentation View].[Time Dimension].[PO Date])<= '6') 
or 
(year([Presentation View].[Time Dimension].[PO Date]) = [Presentation View].[Time Dimensional Fiscal Year].[FYear]-1
and month([Presentation View].[Time Dimension].[PO Date])> '6')